# Vector of pointers as a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I'm doing this project to manage a bank and I'm trying to implement code to edit an employee object.

```
template <class val>
void Bank::updateVector(unsigned int ID, vector<val*> upVector, val* upValue)
{
  deleteByID(ID, upVector);
  upVector.push_back(upValue);
}
```

This is the call to the function:

```
employee *new_employee= new employee(name,birthDate,address,postalCode, NIF,  BI,  phone,  salary,  post,  qualifications, id);
updateVector(id,employees,new_employee);
```

I'm getting an undefined reference error:

```
undefined reference to `void Bank::updateVector<employee>(unsigned int, std::vector<employee*, std::allocator<employee*> >, employee*)'
```

Why is this happening?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you including the definition of `Bank::updateVector`? How does your declaration look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you did it already, but wanna make sure, this should be put in the header where your class is defined.

Comment: Solved it by putting it in the header and passing the vector by reference! Ty

Answer (score 0):

Im not too sure on this
but i think this is happening because you created updateVector as a template yet, you didn't specify the class type

Im pretty sure it would be

```
updateVector <employee> (id, employees, new_employee);
```

Sorry if I got this wrong.

Comment: Nope, template parameters of functions and methods can be inferred by C++ if they appear in the parameter list of the function or method.